# Powershell workflow with reboot

Tags: powershell

I would like to execute PowerShell script from network drive. This script should rename local computer and after reboot join to domain. 
Unfortunately when I try to execute this script nothing happened.

I'm doing it like this:

```
\\networkdrive\reboot-and-join.ps1 MNBC123 domain.intern
```

script:

```
   workflow rename-add-to-domain 
    {
        param ([string]$newcomputername,$domainname)
        Rename-Computer -NewName $computername -force -passthru
        timeout /t 5
        restart-computer -wait
        Add-Computer -domainname $domainname -restart
    }
```

Can you help me how to execute this command right?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To rename a computer to called abhay-123 to aby-dx:

**`RENAME-COMPUTER –computername abhay-123 –newname aby-dx`**

Answer (score 0):

From PowerShell v3 (?) the command Add-Computer supports 'NewName'.

> Add-Computer [-ComputerName ] [-LocalCredential
>   ]  [-UnjoinDomainCredential ] -Credential
>    [-DomainName]  [-OUPath ]  [-Server
>   ] [-Unsecure] [-Options ] [-Restart] [-PassThru]
>   [-NewName ] [-Force]  [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]
>   []

Comment: It doesn't help, because firstly we create reservations for computername via another script in AD as admin and then we rename new computer and connect it to the domain.
I tried it and PS spit out error message: "computer name already exists"

Answer (score 0):

Add-Computer creates a new account in Active Directory, this will cause your error if the account is pre-staged.

Why does the account have to be pre-staged?
You can set the OU the account is created in.

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "Domain02" -OUPath "OU=testOU,DC=domain,DC=Domain,DC=com"
```

The user performing the domain join should be delegated permissions on the target OU.